# Is there way to get counts of every day of week by created_at in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, chart.js, bar-chart

while iam fetching created_at field by using whereDay iam getting this result ?

`"months": ["Thu"]`
`"rq_count_data": [12]`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkGT2.png)

but i need all week days if Monday has no counts it has to put 0 on its position of array element
 likely bellow

`"months": ["Mon","Tue","Wen","THU","Fri","Sat"]`,

`"rq_count_data":["0","0","0","12","0","0"]`,

how can i work like this 
please help me regarding this...

Comment: Whats the column name for months or Mon,Tues,Wed..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkGT2.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkGT2.png in this image I mentioned code.. Iam getting.. That array from database by created_at sir

Comment: Months.. Is the array name.. I named

Comment: So its created_at stores value of Mon,Tues,Wed? You're plucking from it.

Comment: Yes... When I don't have any data I have to days.. Name.. In the same position i want days count.. Bellow element5

Comment: "months": ["Mon","Tue","Wen","THU","Fri","Sat"],

"rq_count_data":["0","0","0","12","0","0"],

Comment: As like the above comment sir.

Comment: rq_count_data":["0","0","0","12","0","0"] this is your original output or your expected output

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding count will not include 0. However in front end you can use HTML if else to get the value 0 for you. Something like

`$months->weeks != null ? $months->weeks : '0'` //If there's a value,show,else i'll be null

Comment: Actually this is for Graphs.. With chartjs.. I have 2 datasets.. One is the submission and other requirements.. That y I have show the labels.. From start of the week to end of the week..

Comment: Ahh..i see.but aren't you gonna loop out the array data as well for graph?

Comment: i have two deffrent datasets and both datasets cant have same range value..but same kind labels...from sunday to saturday

Comment: I see..guess i cant help much because its datasets not tables..Gonna wait for someone's else answer or guidance. :/